# Add caption to "framed" environment

Tags: captions

I am using the following framed environment to write down a pseudo-code algorithm:

```
\underline{Algo} \\
\label{t:label_algorithm}
\begin{framed}
\begin{tabbing}[!htbp]

BLA BLA ALGORITHM TEXT

\end{tabbing}
\end{framed}
```

Wherever I add \caption{SAMPLE CAPTION}, LaTex throws an error...so how exactly can I add a caption?

Thanks

Comment: The `tabbing`  environment is not a float. Try  with `\captionof{algorithm}{SAMPLE CAPTION}`. But why don't you use one of the dedicated packages?

Comment: Didn't know, thx!